# Generating hatched filling using Region functionality

Tags: graphics, version-10, regions, filling

Before v.10 came out there were [several Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=hatched) on generating hatched filling for `Plot`, `ListPlot` etc.

In v.10 we have new **`Region`** functionality and I wonder: **Does it allow a straightforward way to produce *vector* hatched filling for arbitrary 2D `Polygon`?**

Here is my first attempt to use `Region` functionality which produces ugly result in extremely inefficient way:

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];
blob = PolygonData["Blob", "Polygon"];
Show[DiscretizeRegion[
  RegionIntersection[
   RegionUnion @@ 
    Table[InfiniteLine[{-3, y}, {1, 1}], {y, -7, 2, .2}], 
   blob], {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}], Prolog -> blob, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: plot]

Is it a good idea to use `Region` for such purposes? Can anyone suggest an efficient solution?

P.S. I think that raster texture is not appropriate for hatching filling because it is not scalable. **The goal is to have *vector* hatching.**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Update 2:** Finally ... in version 12.1 you can use the new directives [`HatchFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HatchFilling.html) and [`PatternFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternFilling.html):

```
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], #, blob}, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ 
   {HatchFilling[], Directive[Red, HatchFilling[Pi/2, 2, 10]]} // Row
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], PatternFilling[#, ImageScaled[1/20]], blob}, 
    ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {"Diamond", "XGrid"} // Row
```

[image]

**Update:** **Using `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh` in `RegionPlot`**:

```
RegionPlot[Evaluate[Region`RegionProperty[Rationalize /@ blob, {x, y}, 
    "FastDescription"][[1, 2]]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Mesh -> 50, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 &, #1 - #2 &}, MeshStyle -> White, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Blue}]]
```

[image]

With settings `MeshStyle -> GrayLevel[.3], PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thick, LightBlue}]`
[image]

With settings  `Mesh -> {40, 20}, MeshFunctions -> {# #2 &, Norm[{#, #2}] &}, MeshStyle -> White, MeshShading -> Dynamic@{{Hue@RandomReal[], Hue@RandomReal[]}, {Hue@RandomReal[], Hue@RandomReal[]}},` we get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update 2:** **Mesh specifications**

```
rpF = RegionPlot[
    Evaluate[Region`RegionProperty[Rationalize /@ blob, {x, y}, 
       "FastDescription"][[1, 2]]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Mesh -> #,
     MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 &, #1 - #2 &}, 
    MeshStyle -> GrayLevel[.3], 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thick, LightBlue}]] &;

rp1 = rpF@{20, 75};
rp2 = rpF@{List /@ {-5, -4, -2.5, -2., -1.9, -1.8, -1.7, -1., -.5, Sequence @@ Range[0, 5, .2]}, 
  List /@ {Sequence @@ Range[-5., -1, .3], Sequence @@ Range[-1., 1, .1], 1.5, 2., 2.5, 3.}};
rp3 = rpF@RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {2, 50, 1}];
rp4 = rpF@{Transpose[{RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 25], Table[Hue[RandomReal[]], {25}]}], 
  Transpose[{RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 50], Table[Directive[{Thick, Hue[RandomReal[]]}], {50}]}]};

Grid[{{rp1, rp2}, {rp3, rp4}}]
```

[image]

Change the `MeshFunctions` specification to

```
MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}
```

to get

[image]

Use the option

```
MeshShading -> Dynamic@{{Hue@RandomReal[], Hue@RandomReal[]}, 
                        {Hue@RandomReal[], Hue@RandomReal[]}}
```

to get
[image]

---

**Original version:**

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];
blob = PolygonData["Blob", "Polygon"];

RegionPlot[Evaluate[Region`RegionProperty[Rationalize /@ blob, {x, y}, 
    "FastDescription"][[1, 2]]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> texturea]
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot[Evaluate[Region`RegionProperty[Rationalize /@ blob, {x, y}, 
    "FastDescription"][[1, 2]]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> textureb]
```

[image]

where hatched textures  `texturea` and `textureb`

```
texturea = Texture[Rasterize@hatchingF["cross", {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, 100]]
```

[image]

```
textureb = Texture@Rasterize@hatchingF["cross", {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, 100, 
           Dynamic@Directive[{Thick, Hue[RandomReal[]]}]]
```

[image]

are obtained using the function

```
ClearAll[hatchingF];
hatchingF[dir : ("single" | "cross") : "single", 
  slope : ({{_, _} ..}) : {{1, 1}}, mesh_Integer: 100, 
  style_: GrayLevel[.5], pltstyle_: None, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{meshf = Switch[dir, "single", {slope[[1, 1]] #1 + slope[[1, -1]] #2 &}, 
     "cross", {slope[[1, 1]] #1 - slope[[1, -1]] #2 &, 
      slope[[-1, 1]] #1 + slope[[-1, -1]] #2 &}]}, 
  ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Mesh -> mesh,
   MeshFunctions -> meshf, MeshStyle -> style, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   opts, Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, 
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> pltstyle]]
```

More examples:

```
hatchingF["cross", {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, 50, Red]
```

[image]

```
hatchingF["single", {{1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 50, Directive[{Thick,Green}]]
```

[image]

```
texture2 = Texture[Rasterize@ hatchingF["cross", {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, 50, Directive[{Thick, Red}]]];
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> texture2, Mesh -> None, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Comment: I need vector hatching.

Comment: @Alexey, would something like `Texture[ImportString[ ExportString[hatchingF["cross", {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, 100], "PNG"]]]` work?

Comment: `Texture` works only with raster fills. I think that raster hatching is not appropriate for generating publication quality graphics.

Comment: @Alexey, so `Texture` is out; that still leaves `Mesh/MeshFunctions/MeshShading`? :)

Comment: Yes, `MeshFunctions` is a solution. There is an extremely simple way to optimize the mesh: `% /. Line[{{f_, __}, __, {__, l_}}] :> Line[{f, l}]`. The only drawback is that `Mesh` does not allow to specify the distance between the hatches, only the number of hatches. Is there a way to generate completely customizable hatching?

Comment: @Alexey, please see the update re what can be done with various `Mesh` specs.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution which combines kguler's and MichaelE2's approaches:

```
ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ blob, Mesh -> 20, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 - #2 &}, MeshStyle -> Black, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Black, PlotStyle -> None, Axes -> False]
```

[image: plot]

Note however that the syntax form `ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ region]` seems to be undocumented.

---

It is worth to mention that in a usual situation when only the hatching is needed there is straightforward way to optimize it by joining the adjacent line segments:

```
simplifyHatches = # /. Line[{f_Integer, __, l_Integer}] :> Line[{f, l}] &;

ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ blob, Mesh -> 20, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 - #2 &}, MeshStyle -> Black, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> None, 
  Axes -> False] // simplifyHatches
```

[image: optimized plot]

Answer (score 7):

Edit 2: Updated with a non-convex polygon

```
reg = With[{pts = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {15, 2}]},
   Polygon@SortBy[pts, Apply[ArcTan, # - Mean[pts]] &]];
```

You could make a texture and use `RegionPlot`:

```
RegionPlot[
 reg,
 PlotStyle -> Texture[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "MultiSpiralsPattern"}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

Vector graphics through `ContourShading`:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_, y_] := x - y;
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ reg,
 Contours -> 20, ContourShading -> {Blue, LightRed}, 
 ContourStyle -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A self-intersecting polygon:

```
reg = Polygon[RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {15, 2}]];
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ reg,,
 Contours -> Flatten[Table[{c, c + 0.05}, {c, -6, 6, 0.3}]],
 ContourShading -> {Blue, LightRed}, ContourStyle -> None]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The goal is to have vector hatching, not raster.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Perhaps that should be specified in the Q?

Comment: I have updated the Q.

Comment: It seems that you have accidentally deleted your `ContourPlot`-based solution.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I was going to think about it, but I seem to have really deleted it.  It was late and I couldn't figure out the difference between hatching and stripes.  Also, I was running out of energy to address the main question of how to use the new Region functionality to make hatching.  The answers so far don't really use it in the way you were trying.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Another thing I was concerned about is that Lines are different than Polygons. This difference can be significant sometimes when exported to a vector graphics format. `ContourShading` creates only polygons, which behave better than a mixture. Is that a concern for you? (Using Lines for the hatching would be easier.)

Comment: I expected hatches to be `Line`s, not stripes. This is also illustrated in the question: introduction of `InfiniteLine` and `RegionIntersection` give me a hope that now may be possible a straightforward way to get explicit hatching. My original idea was to generate a set of `InfiniteLine`s and then take an intersection with the polygon. I noticed that `Reduce` solves this problem rather quickly. So may be efficient solution should go through `Reduce`.

Comment: I should also notice that I have intentionally chosen non-convex and rather complicated `"Blob"` as an example of a polygon. Your new elegant `{x, y} ∈ reg` solution is surprisingly efficient as compared to the old `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ reg]` approach.

Comment: Is the form `ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ reg]` documented? I just have checked with the `blob` and found that one of the hatches (bottom right) [is absent](http://i.imgur.com/9mDpFw9.png): `ContourPlot[x-y,{x,y}∈blob,Contours->20,PlotRange->All,ContourShading->None,ContourStyle->Black,BoundaryStyle->Black]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It might be a bug. There are 20 contours, which suggests the subdivision of the range of `f[x, y]` is incorrect. `Contours -> 70` is much worse. Disappointing. The domain specification `{x, y} ∈ reg` is not documented per se for plotting functions, but the guide "guide/GeometricSolvers" suggests that region functionality has been incorporated. However, things like `ContourPlot[Norm[p], p ∈ reg]` don't work, but they do in some other functions. (My difficulty with lines was that in math/*M* a line is 1D, while on paper it's just a thin stripe. I'd prefer stripes.)

Comment: It seems that `ParametricPlot[{x,y},{x,y}∈blob,Mesh->20,MeshFunctions->{#1-#2&},MeshStyle->Black,BoundaryStyle->Black,PlotStyle->None,Axes->False]` works fine. This solution can be considered as consolidation of your's and @kguler's ideas.