# How to combine ParametricPlot and RegionPlot?

Tags: graphics, parametric-functions, plotting, implicit

I have two implicitly defined equations. I plot the implicit curve using parametric plot.

```
k3 = 0.4;
n = 4;
k1 = 3;

k2 = (k3*((n - 1)*(s1/k1)^n - 1))/(1 + (s1/k1)^n)^2;
v1 = k2*s1 + (k3*s1)/(1 + (s1/k1)^n);

ParametricPlot[{k2, v1}, {s1, 0.0, 50}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 0.3}, {0, 1.5}}, AspectRatio -> 0.5, 
PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

Now I want to color and hatch the area inside. In another project I used RegionPlot for this (see an example below), but how can I use RegionPlot (or some other technic perhaps) for this example with implicit equations?

[image]

Comment: Strongly related: "[Generating hatched filling](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64159/280)."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To fill with a solid color, you can post-process the `Line` primitive into a `Polygon`

```
ParametricPlot[{k2, v1}, {s1, 0.0, 50}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 0.3}, {0, 1.5}}, AspectRatio -> 0.5, 
 PlotStyle -> Black] /. Line[x_] :> {Blue, Polygon[x]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** Using the approach in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64159/280) mentioned in Alexey's comment:

```
poly = Cases[pp, Line[x_] :> Polygon[x], {0, Infinity}][[1]]; 
Quiet[region = Region`RegionProperty[poly, {x, y}, "FastDescription"][[1, 2]]];

RegionPlot[region, {x, 0, .3}, {y, 0, 1.5}, Mesh -> 50, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 - #2 &}, MeshStyle -> White, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Blue}], PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow, so smart! but I'm still wondering if there is a way to convert this to be suitable for `RegionPlot`.

Comment: @sunt05, please see the update using the same trick in the linked answer.

Answer (score 11):

Probably this match your plot:

```
ParametricPlot[{r {r k2, v1}}, {s1, 0.0, 50}, {r, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 0.3}, {0, 1.5}}, AspectRatio -> 0.5, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], Mesh -> 100, 
 MeshFunctions -> (50 #1 - #2 &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I have tried almost _all_ the wrong ways to get the third argument of  `ParametricPlot` working:)  ( +1)

Comment: some more explanations on the parameterization would be of great help, though that might be more related to math rather than Mathematica:) But definitely an elegant answer!

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: @kguler,  Well I am now very prouder. +1 from you is a big thing because it is not an easy task to impress you:)

Comment: @Algohi, see [vote counts](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all):) By the way, this answer is not an exception by any means -- I learned a lot from your answers; I don't remember one that I wasn't impressed with or did not upvote.

Comment: @kguler I may not express my feeling toward you correctly. I meant you are great. sorry if my words are not correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely, positively insist on using `RegionPlot`, then it's still possible to do with the curve you mentioned.  This is because it's actually possible for your curve to be written as $v_1(k_2)$, albeit in a pretty ugly form.  Start by inverting your relation between $s_1$ and $k_2$:

```
s1solns = Solve[(k3*((n - 1)*(s1/k1)^n - 1))/(1 + (s1/k1)^n)^2 == k2, s1];
```

[image: Ugly solutions for s1(k2)]

Once you've got that, you can replace $s_1$ with these functions of $k_2$ in your expression for $v_1$.   This gives you two functions for $v_1(k_2)$;  the desired region is bounded above by the first function, and below by the second function.  Note that $k_2$ has a maximum value for which these functions are real, which I call $k_{2\text{max}}$ in the code below.

```
params = {k3 -> 0.4, n -> 4, k1 -> 3}; 
v1curves = (k2*s1 + (k3*s1)/(1 + (s1/k1)^n) /. s1solns) /. params;
k2max = k2 /. First[Solve[((k3^2 - 4 k2 k3 n - 2 k3^2 n + k3^2 n^2) /. params) == 0, k2]];
RegionPlot[
 v1 <= v1curves[[1]] && v1 >= v1curves[[2]] && k2 >= 0, 
 {k2, 0, k2max}, {v1, 0, Evaluate[v1curves[[1]] /. k2 -> k2max]}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 6]
```

[image]

This method is, to be honest, a kludgey hack; the above answers are much better, and will generalize much more readily.  But it was still fun to try to do this with one hand tied behind my back.  :-)