# How to fill a region with lines

Tags: filling

How to fill a region with lines:

```
Plot[{t + 1, t}, {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {0, 4},Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

I want to change the filling style to vertical lines, as shown in the right figure below. How should I change the code?
[image]

Comment: In addition to the answe below, you may want to search this site for *"hatched" or "hashed" filling*. There have been a few examples, the best of which seem to rely on using a `RegionPlot` of the region and mesh lines.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Strongly related: "[Generating hatched filling using Region functionality](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64159/280)."

Answer (score 12):

```
funs = {t + 1, t};

Show[{Plot[funs, {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}], 
      RegionPlot[funs[[2]] < y < funs[[1]], {t, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 6}, 
                 Mesh -> 60, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
                 MeshStyle -> {Gray, Thickness[.001]}, PlotStyle -> Transparent]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Just for fun,to show the flexibility of this method:

```
Show[{Plot[funs, {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}], 
  RegionPlot[funs[[2]] < y < funs[[1]], {t, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 6}, 
   Mesh -> 60, MeshFunctions -> {Sin[#1] Sin[#2] &}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None, MeshStyle -> {Gray, Thickness[.001]}, 
   MeshShading -> {Red, Green, None, Yellow}, 
   PlotStyle -> Transparent]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 10):

you could use `GridLines` also

```
Plot[{t + 1, t}, {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[0, 4, .2], None}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {Top, White}, 2 -> {Bottom, White}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I guess the simplest way is:

```
Show[
 ListPlot[{
   Table[i*2 + 1, {i, -1, 3, 0.1}],
   Table[i*2 + 3, {i, -1, 3, 0.1}]}, Joined -> True],
 ListPlot[{
   Table[i*2 + 1, {i, -1, 3, 0.1}],
   Table[i*2 + 3, {i, -1, 3, 0.1}]
   }, Joined -> False, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.001]]
 ]
```

The point-based representation allows to have a discrete line-based filling.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A modification of Rom38's.

```
Show[
 Plot[{t + 1, t}, {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}],
 ListLinePlot[Table[{{i, i + 1}, {i, i}}, {i, 0, 4, 0.2}], PlotStyle -> {{Gray, Thin}}]
 ]
```

[image]

Another option with Epilog:

```
Plot[{t + 1, t}, {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}, 
 Epilog -> Table[Line @ {{i, i}, {i, i + 1}}, {i, 0, 4, 0.2}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using `Epilog`

```
Plot[{t + 1, t}, {t, 0, 4}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 4}, 
 Epilog -> Line /@ (Thread@{#, {# + 1, #}} & /@ Range[0, 4, 0.2])]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another way to get what you are going for, by using `ContourPlot`

```
ContourPlot[#, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, ContourShading -> False, 
    Contours -> 20] & /@ {{x == y,
    x + 1 == y},
   Piecewise[{{x, x < y < x + 1}}, Indeterminate]} // Show
```

[image]