# Filling curves with dashed lines in both directions

Tags: plotting, filling

is there a way to fill the area under the curves with dashed lines (left to right for one curve and right to left for the other) with a transparent filling between lines? I cannot even get dashing under the curve.

```
Show[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> Blue, Filling -> Axis], 
  Plot[Cos[x], {x, 1, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Green, Filling -> Axis, 
   FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.2]]}]
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64159/280)?

Comment: Actually, it helped. the solution to my problem is to use the RegionPlot and Mesh options.