# HatchFilling exports as non-vector graphics

Tags: graphics, export, filling

As of version 12.1, there is an interesting new function to perform object pattern filling: `HatchFilling`

It works great, but it seems that any graphics containing this symbol export as non-vector graphics.

For example,

```
Export["rectangle.pdf", Graphics[{HatchFilling[], Rectangle[]}]]
```

Will create a PDF file with a lossy image, instead of vector graphics.

Is this a bug?

Is there an alternative to this function that can seamlessly fill a graphics object e.g. `Rectangle[]` with this kind of pattern and export as a vector graphics?

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions. See the tag description for more details.

Comment: IMO this is not a bug, but a missing feature. If you want it exported in vector form, the best thing you can do is to contact Wolfram and ask for it. I have already done this a couple of weeks ago, but the number of requests does matter for the priority of an issue.

Comment: Guess you are right, the same occurs when `Texture` is applied to a Graphics object. Maybe this feature is available in the next release.

Comment: "Maybe this feature is available in the next release" Don't count on it. If you want it to happen, report the problem to Wolfram!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RegionPlot` and the options [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) + [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) + [`MeshStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html)

```
RegionPlot[Rectangle[], Mesh -> 50, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 &, #1 - #2 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thin, Blue], Directive[Thin, Red]}, 
 PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Add the option `MeshShading -> {{White, Cyan}, {Orange, White}}` to get

[image]

```
RegionPlot[Rectangle[], Mesh -> 15, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 + 2 #2 &, # - 2 #2 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, White], Directive[Thick, White]}, 
 PlotStyle -> None, 
 MeshShading -> Dynamic[{{RandomColor[], RandomColor[]}, {RandomColor[], 
     RandomColor[]}}],
 BoundaryStyle -> None, Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot[Annulus[], Mesh -> {50, 20}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Sin[# + #2] &, Norm[{# , # - #2}] &}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, White], Directive[Thick, White]}, 
 PlotStyle -> None, 
 MeshShading -> Dynamic[{{RandomColor[], White}, {White, RandomColor[]}}], 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot[Disk[], Mesh -> 20, 
 MeshFunctions -> {# + #2  RandomReal[{1, 1.2}] &, 
     # + #2 RandomReal[{-1.2, -1.}] &}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, White], Directive[Thick, White]}, 
 PlotStyle -> None, 
 MeshShading -> Dynamic[{{RandomColor[], White}, {White, 
     RandomColor[]}}], BoundaryStyle -> None, Frame -> False, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Block[{z = u + I v, pa = PadeApproximant[Exp[z], {z, 0, {5, 0}}]}, 
 RegionPlot[Abs[pa/Exp[z]] > 1, {u, -4, 4}, {v, -4, 4}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> 70, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 &, #1 - #2 &},
  MeshShading -> {{White, Cyan}, {Orange, White}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Blue], 
    Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Red]}, PlotStyle -> None, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, Frame -> False]]
```

[image]

**See also:** [This answer to a related Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64178/125)

Comment: That is a really neat example, changing the value of the `Mesh` parameter will modify the spacing between lines, but how do you change `MeshFunctions` to obtain different angles?

Comment: @GuillermoOliver, I added an example showing how to get different angles.

Comment: In case I have to combine it with other `Graphics`, how should I do this? Using this `RegionPlot` approach results in an error message: `GraphicsBox is not a Graphics primitive or directive`.

Comment: @GuillermoOliver, you can use `Show[RegionPlot[....], Graphics[....], PlotRange->All]`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I guess the vectorization issue with `HatchFilling` will be addressed in the next version of `Mathematica`.

Answer (score 3):

I have written a quick and dirty function to fill rectangular shapes with lines. It is not generalizable, it only works with rectangular shapes and for angles less than 90 degrees, but maybe it can be useful for someone.

```
RectangleLineFill[min_, max_, step_, angle_] := {
   Table[Line[{
      {i, min[[2]]},
      {Min[(max[[2]] - min[[2]])/Tan[angle] + i, max[[1]]], 
       min[[2]] + (Min[(max[[2]] - min[[2]])/Tan[angle] + i, 
            max[[1]]] - i)*Tan[angle]}
      }], {i, min[[1]], max[[1]], step}],
   Table[Line[{
      {min[[1]], i},
      {Min[(max[[2]] - i)/Tan[angle] + min[[1]], max[[1]]], 
       i + (Min[(max[[2]] - i)/Tan[angle] + min[[1]], max[[1]]] - 
           min[[1]])*Tan[angle]}
      }], {i, min[[2]] + step, max[[2]], step}]
   } /. {Line[{x_, y_}] -> If[x == y, Null, Line[{x, y}]]}
```

Usage example:

```
Graphics[{Red, RectangleLineFill[{0, 0}, {3, 2}, 1/10, 45 \[Degree]]}]
```

[image: Rectangle fill]