# Two-color HatchFilling

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

Is there an easy way to make `HatchFilling` use two alternating colors?  E.g.

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
 RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, HatchFilling[0, 10, 20]}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but without calling `RegionPlot` twice, since my real region to be plotted is computationally expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `HatchFilling` does not support different colors for the lines and spacings. We can hack it as follows to color the spacings:

```
ClearAll[wthack]
wthack[clr_ : Blue][{d___, h_HatchFilling}] := PatternFilling[
  ColorReplace[Graphics[{d, h, Rectangle[]}], White -> clr], ImageScaled[1]]
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[{ RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
   PlotStyle -> wthack[][{Red, HatchFilling[0, 10, 20]}]],
  Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
   Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, Pink}, 
    2 -> {Axis, wthack[Opacity[.5, Yellow]][{Blue, HatchFilling[Pi/3, 10, 30]}]}}]}, 
  Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: For `RegionPlot` you can  use the options `MeshFunctions` + `Mesh` + `MeshShading` to get the desired styling . See, for example, [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64159/125).