# HatchFilling between two data sets in LogLog scale for Mathematica 11.1

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

Need to fill the region between two data sets with colored hatched (\ || //) lines in LogLog scale. I use Mathematica 11.1. Apparently HatchFilling nor PatternFilling are available.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[addHatchFilling]
addHatchFilling[meshfunctions_: Automatic, meshstyle_: Automatic, 
   mesh_: Automatic, meshshading_: Automatic] := 
  ReplaceAll[p_Polygon :> {p, 
    First[RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[p], 
     MeshFunctions -> (meshfunctions /. Automatic -> {# + #2 &}), 
     MeshStyle -> (meshstyle /. Automatic -> Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], White]),
     Mesh -> (mesh /. Automatic -> 40), 
     MeshShading -> (meshshading /. Automatic -> None)]]}] @* Normal;
```

***Examples:***

```
{list1, list2} = {Transpose[{Range @ 20, Range @ 20}], 
   Transpose[{Range @ 20, Sqrt @ Range @ 20}]};

llp = ListLogLogPlot[{list1, list2}, Joined -> True, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, ImageSize -> 400];

Row[{llp, addHatchFilling[] @ llp}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
Row[{addHatchFilling[{# &}, 
    Directive[Opacity[1], CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[5], Orange], 30]@llp, 
  addHatchFilling[{# &, #2 &}, Automatic, {20, 20}] @ llp}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
Row[{addHatchFilling[{#2 &}, 
    Directive[Opacity[1], CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[2], Red],
    20, 
    {Opacity[1, Cyan], Opacity[1, Yellow]}] @ llp, 
  addHatchFilling[{# + #2 &, #2 - # &}, 
    Automatic, 
    {20, 10}, 
    {{Opacity[1, Red], None}, {None, Opacity[1, Yellow]}}] @ llp}, 
  Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> ```
>  "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
> ```

**See also:** [Generating hatched filling using Region functionality](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64178/125)

Comment: Appreciate the prompt response@kglr. Also one can add  PlotStyle -> Transparent , to the module for superimposing on other colored plots.