# Plot with lines highlighting different regions

Tags: plotting, version-11.3, grid-lines

I want to plot  `Plot[{Sin[x], 0.3}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]` with the portion below `0.3` highlighted as by lines as shown

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** For version older than v 12.1 `HatchFilling` is not available. You can construct filling using `RegionPlot` with the options [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) + [`MeshStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html) (as in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64178/125)) and use it as `Epilog` in `Plot`:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], 0.3}, {x, 0, 2 π}, 
 Epilog -> First[RegionPlot[0 < y <= .3, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> 20, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#1 - 2 #2 &}, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Orange, CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[2]], 
    PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None]]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can use the option [`Filling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html) as follows:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], 0.3}, {x, 0, 2 π}, 
  Filling -> 
   {2 -> {0, Directive[Opacity[.5], Orange, HatchFilling["Diagonal", 1, 5]]}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`Filling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html) + [`FillingStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FillingStyle.html):

```
Plot[{Sin[x], 0.3}, {x, 0, 2 π}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> 0}, 
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Pink, HatchFilling["Diagonal", 5, 10]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but  HatchFilling does not seem to be available in Mathematica 11.3

Comment: @Mike, please see the update.