# How to use lines as textures in a plot

Tags: plotting, filling

I would like to replicate this plot:

[image]

From *[A parametric model for dark energy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.1713.pdf)*.

But how can I add the lines and the grids to the various sections?

Comment: if you have version 12.1+ try [HatchFilling](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HatchFilling.html) and [PatternFilling](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternFilling.html).

Comment: closely related / possible duplicate: [Generating hatched filling using Region functionality](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64159/125)

Comment: holy f, this is amazing. thanks kglr, i will try this evening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
inequalities = {y >= -x,
   y < -x && x >= -.45, 
   5 + 5 x <= y <= -x - 1.1, 
   Min[5 + 5 x, -x] >= y >= -x - 1.1 &&   x <= -.45};

regions = ImplicitRegion[{#}, {{x, -3/2, 0}, {y, -2,   2}}] & /@ inequalities;

labels = {"forbidden", "decelerated", "phantom", "quintessence"};

fillings = {PatternFilling["Diamond", ImageScaled[1/50]],
    HatchFilling[-Pi/4],
    HatchFilling[Pi/2],
    HatchFilling[]};

 legends = SwatchLegend[fillings /. ImageScaled[_] -> ImageScaled[1/4], 
  inequalities, LegendMarkerSize -> 30]

 epilog = MapThread[Text[Style[Framed[#, Background -> White, FrameStyle -> White], 
      16], RegionCentroid @ #2, Center] &, {labels, regions}];

 RegionPlot[Evaluate @ regions,
  PlotRange -> {{-3/2, 0}, {-2, 2}},
  ImageSize -> Large,
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black],
  Epilog -> epilog,
  PlotLegends -> legends,
  PlotStyle -> Thread[Directive[Black, fillings]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For versions before 12.1, we can use [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) and [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) to get a similar look:

```
inequalities = {y >= -x,
   y < -x && x >= -.45, 
   5 + 5 x <= y <= -x - 1.1, 
   Min[5 + 5 x, -x] >= y >= -x - 1.1 && x <= -.45};

regions = ImplicitRegion[{#}, {{x, -3/2, 0}, {y, -2, 2}}] & /@ inequalities;

labels = {"forbidden", "decelerated", "phantom", "quintessence"};

meshfunctions = {{4 # + 3/2 #2 &, 3/2 #2 - 4 # &}, 
   {# + #2 &}, 
   {# &},
   {# - #2 &}};

meshes = {{80, 100}, 60, 30, 50};


epilog = MapThread[Text[Style[Framed[#, Background -> White, FrameStyle -> White], 14],
    RegionCentroid @ #2, Center] &, 
   {labels, regions}];

rp = Show[MapThread[
       RegionPlot[#, 
        PlotRange -> {{-3/2, 0}, {-2, 2}}, 
        MeshFunctions -> #2, 
        Mesh -> #3, 
        MeshStyle -> Darker@Gray, 
        ImageSize -> 400, 
        BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
        PlotStyle -> None] &, 
      {regions, meshfunctions, meshes}], 
  Epilog -> epilog]
```

[image]

Adding a hatch-filled legend requires additional work: We can create `RegionPlot`s with desired hatching patterns using `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh` as above and use them as legend markers making use of the (undocumented) option `"LegendItem"` for `LineLegend`:

```
hatchLegend = RegionPlot[True, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
    Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks -> False, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
    ImagePadding -> 1, 
    PlotRangeClipping -> False,
    MeshFunctions -> #,
    Mesh -> #2, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], #3], 
    ImageSize -> 30, 
    FrameStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Black], 
    PlotStyle -> None] &;


legenditems = MapThread[hatchLegend, 
     {ReplacePart[{1} -> {# + #2 &, #2 - # &}] @ meshfunctions, 
     {10, 10, 7, 10},
     ConstantArray[Darker @ Gray, 4]}];

legend = LineLegend[{White, Gray, Gray, Gray}, 
   inequalities, 
   "LegendItem" -> legenditems, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 20}];

Legended[rp, legend]
```

[image]